# Полоса анимации при загрузке страницы

Tags: css, css-animation

На сайте https://www.sofiapapadopoulou.com/#front-page/1 при загрузке снизу вверх выезжает полоса.

Помогите советом как реализовать? 
Читаю про анимацию, но практически все источники объясняют как это сделать только как hover эффект.

Спасибо!

Comment: Не уверен или подойдет для загрузки страницы, но как вариант в [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/progress/) есть полоса прогресса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 3px;
  height: 0;
  background: #000;
  animation: move 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  to{
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="line"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Илья, спасибо!